# Angular-routing: Routing link in html-template can't be matched with a route defined in the routing-modules

Tags: angular, angular-router, angular-routerlink, angular-route-segment

I have one question regarding routing (multiple routes inside the module, lazy loading).

Suppose I have 2 modules

1-app.routing.module.ts
2-user.management.routing.module.ts

Inside the app routing module file, I have

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
 { path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full' },
 { path: 'login',  loadChildren: () => import('../app/user.management/user.management.module')
 .then(m => m.UserManagementModule) }
]
 
@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModules {}
```

and inside user management routing module file

```
const userManagementRouting: Routes = [
 { path: '', component: LoginComponent },
 { path: 'forgot-password', component: ForgotPasswordComponent }
];
 
@NgModule({
 imports: [RouterModule.forChild(userManagementRouting)],
 exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class UserManagementRoutingModule { }
```

When I run the app using "ng serve", it works as expected. I have added a link like

```
<a class="btn btn-link" routerLink="/forgot-password">Forgot Password </a>
```

when I clicked on forgot password link the app throw error

```
"Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: cannot match any routes. URL segment: 'forgot-password'"
"Cannot match any routes. URL segment: 'forgot password"
```

Can you please guide me here on what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Looks like this `routerLink="/forgot-password"` should be `routerLink="/login/forgot-password"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the suggestion of R. Richards didn't work either try

```
routerLink=['/forgot-password']
```

or

```
routerLink=['/login/forgot-password']
```

Note that you're using a relative path. So where is this Html-template located?

You could also use an absolute path.

Please let us know if it doesn't work out. Take care and good luck.

Comment: [routerLink]="'/login/forgot-password'"  works.